# I Can't Get My i-class Icons to Show

Tags: html, icons, font-awesome

I can't figure out why my i-class icons won't show! Like wtf is wrong? Everything is coded correctly! Thanks in advance for your help!

Here's  an excerpt of my html code:

```
<div class="social-media-icon-footer">

<div>
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square"  aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</div>
<div>
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</div>
<div>
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</div>
<!-- -->
</div>
```

I also have this link within my `<head></head>` tags: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> . So what is the problem? I don't know!`

Answer (score 0):

I tried it on a project of mine and it worked...

Why don't you try to use this link instead `<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">`

Cheers

[editor img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4mom.png) [result img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMWCn.png)

Check also this info, it could help you

1. https://www.templatemonster.com/help/font-awesome-icons-dont-show.html
2. https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: that is absolutely weird! Why does it work on yours and not on mines? Can you provide a snapshot? I also tried the link you sent me, and it still doesn't work...

Comment: @codebwoy I added in my answer the screenshots and two links for troubleshooting

Comment: @bBlackNina, I am going to try these and let you know what happens!

Comment: Here's a fiddle for a repro - and to prove the correctness of BlackNina's solution! https://jsfiddle.net/taatz6kx/  Perhaps your .social-media-icon-footer has some weird negative margin that would just hide the content? It might be useful if you posted a larger snippet of your site and the original CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I use recently SVG with JS.

But, I had the same problem that you, and changing the link, with the actual link indicated in https://fontawesome.com/get-started/web-fonts-with-css it works well:

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">

<html>
</head></head>
<body>

<i class="fab fa-facebook-square fa-7x"></i>
</body>
</html>
```

Here you can see all icons:
https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery